# tt_content elements with a pid value of -1: what is the reason?

Tags: typo3

Many of tt_content elements of one of my installations do have pid values of -1 (minus one). Why? What function causes negative pids? 
(TYPO3 6.2)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Negative PIDs are mostly caused by enabled workspaces in a TYPO3 system. Records that are not LIVE yet receive PID -1.

This makes very sure that those records will not appear in the frontend until they are approve for the Live state. In addition to the negative PID, those records got some values in their t3ver_-fields in the database which are pointing to the used Workspace, the original element and other information.